# Linking Vatimalei ha'aretz

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-noach, parashas-shemos

In the beginning of Sefer Shemot ([1:7](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9862#showrashi=true)), the text describes the population of Beni Yisrael as growing at such a rate that "vatimalei ha'aretz otam" the land was full of them. This construction appears only one other time in the 5 Books of Moses (Bereishit [6:11](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8171#showrashi=true)) which reads "vatimalei ha'aretz chamas" -- and the land was filled with corruption/robbery (depending on translation).

Does anyone know of any commentary which connects the two verses, possibly explaining the proliferation of the Jewish people, unchecked, as, in and of itself, a problem? Any other connection would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20169/discussion-on-question-by-danno-linking-vatimalei-haaretz).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Baal HaTurim writes in Genesis (5: 11):

> ותמלא הארץ. ב' דסמיכי הכא ואידך ותמלא הארץ אותם. שהארץ עצמה היתה מלאה מהם שהיו יולדות ששה בכרס אחד והיו נבלעים תחת הקרקע ואח''כ מבצבצים ועולים והכי נמי הארץ עצמה היתה מלאה חמס שהיה מפקיד כיסו אצל חברו ואפרסמון עמו והיה הנפקד מניח הכיס עם האפרסמון תחת הקרקע עם אוצרותיו והמפקיד בא בלילה ומריח האפרסמון ולוקח הכל:

To paraphrase: The usage in Exodus "and the land became full of them" reflects the Midrashic interpretation that the ground itself swallowed the abundance of Jewish children. So too, the usage in Genesis reflects the fact that rather than merely filing the land with corruption, they filled the ground itself, as it were, with corruption. For example one would deposit money with a scented tracker. Then, after the guardian buried the money with his own valuables, the depositor would follow the scent to the subterranean trove and plunder it.

This explanation is quoted by the Chida in Chomas Anach to Genesis (5:11) as well.

Comment: It is worth noting that this approach of finding similar expressions and weaving them together is not a universal one among the commentators. It seems to have been non-existent or at least obscure until the Chassidei Ashkenaz popularized it as an exegetical tool along with Gematrios and the like. Even then, many a commentator e.g. Rasag, Rashbam, Ibn Ezra, Rambam, his son, Radak, etc. would not employ such methods (as far as I know). Even those who do, probably ask such question of common wording in order to introduce a cute answer; not because the question is inherently troubling.

Comment: Note also the Tur's wording in his introduction to his Torah commentary (Tur al HaTorah) where he describes the two parts of his commentary. The actual commentary, and also "several parp'raos laTorah" that he included as a separate portion. Through some quirk of history, it was the "cute" secondary portion that was popularized.

Answer (score -2):

They assimilated, they were, everywhere even in theatres, you could say the same about verse speaking about Chamas, it was as well everywhere.

Comment: so is there any commentary you know which connects the negative implications via the phrase?

Comment: I don't know, don't have access to beis-medrash in my place.